# extjs4 and php issue - 500 Internal server error when creating entries

Tags: php, sql

I've been stuck with this problem for a day now. I think I'm overlooking something simple but I can't see it.

I am developing a web application where the user fills up forms and the forms get saved in the database. However, I'm having a problem inserting values to a form. The database does not update and I get a 500 Internal Server Error at the console.

Here is the controller that I call when the user saves the form that was filled up

```
var personStore = Ext.getStore('personBaseDetails');
var caStore = Ext.getStore('creditApplication');
var form = button.up('form').getForm();
var id = personStore.first().get('ID');

//use this to update
if(caStore.count() < 1){
    var creditApplication = Ext.ModelManager.create({
    }, 'app.model.creditApplicationModel');

    caStore.add(creditApplication);

}

var record = caStore.first();
form.updateRecord(record);

caStore.getProxy().extraParams = {
    selectedUserID: id
};

caStore.sync({
    success: function(batch) {
        console.log(batch.operations[0].request.scope.reader.jsonData['message']);
    },

    failure: function(batch) {
        console.log("Failed syncing ca");
    }

});
```

I have checked with various console.log statements that all of the variables here have the proper values.

Here is the php file that gives the 500 Internal Server Error problem:

```
<?php

require_once('../../db_connection.php');
require_once '../../lib/response.php';
require_once '../../lib/request.php';

class creditApplication{    
    var $ID_PERSON;
    var $APPLICATION_TYPE;
    var $APPLICATION_SUB_TYPE;
    var $APPLICATION_NUMBER;
    var $CUSTOMER_NUMBER;
    var $DATE;
    var $STATUS;
    var $ID_UNIT;   
}

$request = new Request(array());

if(isset($request->params)){

    var $selectedCustomer = '';

    if(isset($_GET['selectedUserID'])){

        $selectedCustomer = $_GET['selectedUserID'];

        $array_r=$request->params;
        $inputData = new creditApplication();

        $inputData->ID_PERSON=$selectedCustomer;
        $inputData->APPLICATION_TYPE=($array_r->APPLICATION_TYPE);
        $inputData->APPLICATION_SUB_TYPE=($array_r->APPLICATION_SUB_TYPE);

        $inputData->APPLICATION_NUMBER='sample application number';
        $inputData->CUSTOMER_NUMBER='sample customer number';
        $inputData->DATE='2014-4-4';
        $inputData->STATUS=42;
        $inputData->ID_UNIT='sampleUnit';

        $query="INSERT INTO CREDIT_APPLICATION (ID_PERSON, APPLICATION_TYPE, APPLICATION_SUB_TYPE, APPLICATION_NUMBER,
        CUSTOMER_NUMBER, DATE, STATUS, ID_UNIT) 
            VALUES ($inputData->ID_PERSON, 
            '$inputData->APPLICATION_TYPE', 
            '$inputData->APPLICATION_SUB_TYPE',
            '$inputData->APPLICATION_NUMBER', 
            '$inputData->CUSTOMER_NUMBER',
            '$inputData->DATE', 
            $inputData->STATUS,
            '$inputData->ID_UNIT')";

            $result = mysql_query($query);

            //object response
            $res = new Response();
            $res->success = true;
            $res->message = "Created user";

            print_r($res->to_json());

    }
    else{
        $res = new Response();
        $res->success = false;
        $res->message = "Error - no userID";
        $res->data = array();
        print_r($res->to_json());

    }
}
else{
    $res = new Response();
    $res->success = false;
    $res->message = "Error - no request";
    $res->data = array();
    print_r($res->to_json());
}

?>
```

All the database rows are varchars except for ID_PERSON and STATUS which are ints (hence the single quotes in the insert) and the DATE which is of date format.

Now, I've tried hard coding the values, commenting out the if else conditions, and calling the php file through `localhost:8888/..../createCreditApplication.php` and it actually works. The problem happens when I bring back the if-else blocks and get the values passed to the php file.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: A 500 error in PHP means _go check your web server's error log_. The error will be detailed there. But always when developing code, make sure you have error reporting turned up and displaying errors on screen. At the top of your PHP script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify that I'm running the web app locally as of the moment.

Comment: Running locally is apparent from `localhost:8888` - but there is still an error log somewhere for your local server. But if you enable display_errors at runtime with those 2 function calls, you won't need to go to the log.